# SecureCRT: VBScript printing output to console

Tags: vbscript, secure-crt

I have written script to connect from my local machine to Jump server using secure crt. i was able to execute the script and capture the output into Msgbox, But unable to print it to console.

Below is the code which i have written.

```
    #$language = "VBScript"
#$interface = "1.0"
Set objTab = crt.GetScriptTab
Set g_shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Public szData

crt.Sleep 6000

    objTab.Screen.IgnoreEscape = True
    objTab.Screen.Synchronous = True

    Dim szCommand, szPrompt, nRow, szLogFileName, nIndex

    Do
        bCursorMoved = objTab.Screen.WaitForCursor(1)
    Loop until bCursorMoved = False

    nRow = objTab.Screen.CurrentRow
    szPrompt = objTab.screen.Get(nRow, _
                                 0, _
                                 nRow, _
                                 objTab.Screen.CurrentColumn - 1)
    szPrompt = Trim(szPrompt)

crt.Screen.Synchronous = True

Dim pran

Sub Main

    strVal = crt.Arguments(0)

    crt.Screen.Send "pwd" & chr(13)
    crt.Screen.WaitForString "[xyz@xlpv0002 ~]$"
    crt.Screen.Send "sh test.sh" & chr(9) & chr(13)

    **szData = CaptureOutputOfCommand("sh test.sh", "[xyz@xlpv0002 ~]")  & vbCr**   
    'MsgBox(szData)
    pran = szData

    crt.Clipboard.Format = "CF_TEXT"
    crt.Clipboard.Text = pran

    crt.Dialog.MessageBox("Text is now in the clipboard: \n\n" + crt.Clipboard.Text)
    'MessageBox.Show(szData)

    If Not SendExpect("exit", "[xyz@xlpv0002 ~]") then exit sub

    g_shell.Run "%comspec% /c taskkill /IM SecureCRT.exe /F"

End Sub

'=======================================================================
Function CaptureOutputOfCommand(szCommand, szPrompt)
    if crt.Session.Connected <> True then
        CaptureOutputOfCommand = "[ERROR: Not Connected.]"
        exit function
    end if

    objTab.Screen.Send szCommand & vbcr
    objTab.Screen.WaitForString vbcr
    CaptureOutputOfCommand = objTab.Screen.ReadString(szPrompt)

End Function
'======================================================================
Function SendExpect(szSend, szExpect)
    if objTab.Session.Connected <> True then exit function

    objTab.Screen.Send szSend & vbcr
    objTab.Screen.WaitForString szExpect

    SendExpect = True
End Function
'========================================
```

I am capturing the script output into szData  variable. Is there a way to print the same in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You are already using the command

```vb
crt.Screen.Send
```

You just need to pass a valid command that will output to the console, if doing this on a Windows Server you should be able to use the Command Line program `ECHO` to output to the console.

```vb
crt.Screen.Send "echo Display in console!!!"
```

Output *(untested, but should produce)*

```
Display in console!!!
```

So you should just be able to do

```vb
crt.Screen.Send "echo " & szData
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Scripting Essentials:
  A Guide to Using
  VBScript in SecureCRT](https://www.vandyke.com/support/tips/scripting/scripting_essentials.pdf) *(official documentation)*

Comment: Thank you Lankymart ! . But problem is,  i am running VB script from windows desktop and executing a linux shell script present in RHEL Jump server,  i want the output of the linux scipt to be printed in the windows command prompt. so that i can parse the output.

Comment: @Praneeth Well that's a lot of information that would have been useful in the original question. How am I supposed to know that if you don't mention it?

Comment: @Praneeth You're executing the Linux Shell script from what exactly, the Windows Command Prompt perhaps?

Comment: Really sorry for that.. yes i am running the script from windows command prompt
Command : `"C:\Users\praneeth\Desktop\secureCRT\Test>securecrt.exe /SCRIPT "C:\Users\praneeth\Desktop\secureCRT\Test\oswatch_drv.vbs" /ARG "ls -l" /S "linuxpv0002.intl.com"`

Comment: i tried using Wscript.Echo to print the contents of the variable. But it is not working.

Comment: @Praneeth when you say it's not working, in what way? Does it error, if so what is the error. Does in just not print out anything? or does it print out something your not expecting?